# How to show 6 images in each slide of flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, flexslider

I have a question on flexslider
I am trying to build a slider using flexslider such that

- For desktop (window screen size >= 1200 px), I have six horizonttal images in each slides

  - For mobile or tablet (window screen size < 1200px), I have four images in each slide such that the four images are in a 2 by 2 grid always

Here is a sample codepen 
https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/LLJzgM

I have it almost working. In mobile, I am seeing 4 images in 2 by 2 grid. However, in desktop, I see 6 images for the first slide. For the subsequent slides, I also expected 6 images like the first ones. However I am seeing all the remaining.

I am slicing it as below and wrapping ul

```
// Wrap uls
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i += dataItem) {
  item.slice(i, i + dataItem).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
}
```

However, I think I must have made mistake in slicing probably. May someone please see if this can be made such that in desktop we have 6 images horizontally for each slides keeping everything else as it is now.

My html looks like

```
<div id="flexslider" class="flexslider" data-item="4">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>
    <li class="item"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" alt="placeholder image"></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my scss code looks like below

```
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .flexslider {
      .slides {
          .items {
              display: flex !important;
              flex-wrap: wrap !important;

              item {
                  border: 1px solid red;
              }
          }

          .item {
              background: #ccc;
              margin: 10px;
              padding: 5px;
              text-align: center;
              flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
              /* Need to tweak!*/
              list-style-type: none;
          }
      }
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .flexslider {
      .slides {
          .items {
              display: flex !important;
              //flex-wrap: wrap !important;
              item {
                  border: 1px solid red;
              }
          }

          .item {
              background: #ccc;
              margin: 10px;
              padding: 5px;
              text-align: center;
              flex-basis: calc(100% / 6);
              /* Need to tweak!*/
              list-style-type: none;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

And my js looks like below

```
var fs = $(".flexslider"),
  dataItem = fs.data("item"),
  item = fs.find(".item");

//console.log('item', item.length);

//var dataItem = $(".flexslider").attr("data-type");
if ($(window).width() >= 1200) {
  var el = document.getElementById("flexslider");
  el.setAttribute("data-item", "6");
  dataItem = el.getAttribute("data-item");
}

console.log('dataItem', dataItem);
console.log('length of item', item.length);

// Wrap uls
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i += dataItem) {
  item.slice(i, i + dataItem).wrapAll('<ul class="items"></ul>');
}

// Initialize flexslider
$(window).load(function() {
  fs.flexslider({
    selector: ".slides > .items",
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    directionNav: true,
    slideshow: false,
    smoothHeight: true,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: 1,
    maxItems: 1
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> On desktop versions, I only want to see 6 images.. But I see 6 + 1/2 of 7 sometimes and sometimes 5 and 1/2 of left and right

Maxwidth is 1200px. So if you want to show 6 items, each item will have only `200px` right? But in your css code, you have margin: 20px for each item.That means each item will take 240px.

For 2x2 grid view on Mobile, my solution is you will have a new html structure to show 2 images on each `<li>` tag.

This is my demo code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjMRdG

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing that out.
Especially for mobile, what do you suggest? Is it ok to create a codepen showing the html structure etc?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question as I was able to get it working almost. However, now it is broken in desktop. If you have some time to give this a try, I will appreciate a lot

Comment: Good job, I see everything almost ok in desktop, right?